# Retreiving BLOB value from Database using OutputStreamBlob.class of ojdbc jar file

Tags: java, oracle, ojdbc

In jdbc thin applicattion,if we want to retrieve photo(BLOB) from database we get inputstream object by

> InputStream is= rs.getBinaryStream(columnIndex);

which internally creates an object of

```
oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleBlobInputStream
```

but while  with outputstream we have to create explicitly outputstream object as like

> OutputStream os=new FileOutputStream("folder path");

Why we cant we use  `oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleBlobOutputStream.class` of ojdbc6.jar for getting os object.

Why we have to create explicitly .hope u guys can help me,thanks in advance

Comment: What do you mean, you have to create explicit output stream? The input stream is used to read the data (Photo), so why would you want an output stream?

Comment: i create output stream obj to point to folder to where i want to write data(photo)(destination) from inputstream(source) using buffer as a mediator

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `ResultSet` provides you with methods for **retrieving** the values from the SQL query. For a Blob, you can get that data in 3 forms:

- Byte array (`getBytes`)
- Input stream (`getBinaryStream`)
- Blob object (`getBlob`)

What you do with that data is entirely up to you. If you want to turn around and save that data to a file, you must do that using the `FileOutputStream` and write the data to that stream.

The `ResultSet` interface cannot possibly implement methods to sending the data to all possible places. What if you wanted to use the Photo in a Swing application? Or send it to a server using FTP, WebDAV, HTTP, ... You really think that should be the responsibility of `ResultSet`?

Comment: thank you andreas for clearing my doubt,as ResultSet is not capable of it so,we are creating an object of FileOutputStream  to send the files to destination..

Comment: @RameshRaj You're welcome. Please accept this as the answer then, so others can easily see it.